# probability in percentage

Tags: probability

a survey conducted within a campus shows that 63% students are excellent in mathematics, 34% are excellent in English and 27% students are excellent in both Mathematics and English. calculate the percentage of students who are excellent in either mathematics or english?

refer to the formula P(A v B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∧ B), 
probability of English or probability of Mathematic need to over 1.24 or 0.97?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Please edit your post to include some of your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\text{ and }B) \rightarrow \\ P(\text{excellent in mathematics or English})=P(\text{excellent in mathematics})+P(\text{excellent in English})-P(\text{excellent in mathematics and English})=0.63+0.34-0.27=0.70=\boxed{70\%}$